# Electron and vuejs changes are not detected

Tags: javascript, node.js, vuejs2, electron

I have a problem with Electron and vuejs.

I'm doing a treatment in the node application on an object but vuejs doesn't detect the change of the variable. (I have to refresh the page to display the new message.)

I tried to place the variable in global and mainWindows but nothing to do.

Is there a solution to my problem?

**How to reproduce kickly:**
`npm init` & `npm install --save electron` & `mkdir pages`

**Create ./`index.js`:**

```
const electron = require('electron');
const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');
let mainWindow;
function createWindow()
{
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800, height: 800, backgroundColor: '#ffffff'
    });

    //Stock data in window
    mainWindow.infos = {
        foo: 'HelloFromMainWindows'
    }

    //Stock data in global
    global.infos = {
        foo: 'HelloFromGLobal'
    }

    //Ez Way to load url
    mainWindow.LoadPage = function (name)
    {
        this.loadURL(url.format({
            pathname: path.join(__dirname, '/pages/' + name),
            protocol: 'file:',
            slashes: true
        }));
    };
    mainWindow.LoadPage('index.html');
    mainWindow.on('closed', function ()
    {    
        mainWindow = null;
    });
}
app.on('ready', createWindow);
app.on('window-all-closed', function ()
{
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin')
        app.quit();
});
app.on('activate', function ()
{
    if (mainWindow === null)
        createWindow();
});
```

**Create `./pages/index.html`:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <h2> {{ foo }} </h2>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /*--1.From Html (No Need to Refresh)--*/
        let infos = { foo: 'HelloFromHtml'}

        /*--2.From CurrentWindow (Need Refresh)--*/
        //let { remote } = require('electron');
        //let currentWindow = remote.getCurrentWindow();
        //let infos = currentWindow.infos;

        /*--3.From Global (Need Refresh)--*/   
        //let infos = require('electron').remote.getGlobal('infos');

        //Just the call to vuejs
        let vue = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: infos
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Run with :** `cd .\node_modules\electron\dist\` & `.\electron.exe ..\..\..\index.js`

Just open a console in electon chrome view and type `infos.foo =' helloDetected';` to see the difference between the 3 code blocks. (You just have to uncomment the html code sections that I specified).

**For the first part :** `/*--1.From Html (No Need to Refresh)--*/`

- The data is refreshed instantly

**For the second and third part :** `/*--2.From CurrentWindow (Need Refresh)--*/` & `/*--3.From Global (Need Refresh)--*/`

- The data is *NOT* refreshed instantly
- I need to refresh the page to refresh the message (with `CTRL + R`)

**Edit :**
I think I found the problem. Electron add functions for handle when value changes and vuejs as well. (get and set)
I don't know what the cleanest solution here is. Must edit vuejs or electron sources?

[Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bQiM.png)

- infos is a electron object in the mainWindow
- data is a vuejs object in the Vue

Comment: Not in a position to run this but try: 1) data should be a function. `data: function () { return { infos: '' } }. Also tr move your `new Vue` to the top of the script.

I can try run this later today if that doesn't help.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure I understand :/ ...

i replace this : 
     `mainWindow.infos = {
        foo: 'HelloFromMainWindows'
     }`

By this : 

    `mainWindow.infos = () => {
        return {foo: 'HelloTestFromNewInstance'}
    }`

in my `index.js`, but still not working...

Answer (score 0):

I found an example of sending messages from the main process to the renderer process, maybe it's the right way to do.

https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-contents.md#contentssendchannel-arg1-arg2-

`index.js`:

```
// test send event
setTimeout(function() {
    mainWindow.webContents.send('foo', 'whoooooooh!')
}, 2000);
```

`pages/index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <h2> {{ foo }} </h2>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        let { remote, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
        let currentWindow = remote.getCurrentWindow();
        // get initial foo
        let infos = currentWindow.infos;

        // listen for foo change
        ipcRenderer.on('foo', (event, message) => {
            vue.foo = message
        })

        //Just the call to vuejs
        let vue = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data () {
                return {
                    foo: infos.foo
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes but this method needs to call a `mainWindow.webContents.send('foo', 'whoooooooh!')`each time i modify my `infos.foo`. And replicate all values in an object in the render process... Not a good solution for me :/  sry. 

Vuejs does not override getters and setters because properties are `configurable false`. I'll try to recompile electron by modifying this and edit vuejs to call the 
`ipcRenderer. sendSync (' ELECTRON_BROWSER_MEMBER_SET', metaId, member. name, args)` in setters and getters to see if it solves the problem.